# 10 months no movement on my tires

Tags: tires

I have parked my Ferrari California in a covered car park for 10 months. I have removed battery, but does anyone know if it is safe to drive with the tires it has? I will be taking the car for a trip. Any suggestions on the tires? Tnx

Answer (score 1):

Long term storage like that usually means the vehicle weight is taken off the tyres with some stands as this may cause « flat-spots » .

If you drive it hard or long periods then the tyres may fail due to these flat spots now flexing.

IMHO you should consider replacing them , at leat have them checked by somebody competant...

This would have been a good question at the start of the 10 months...

Comment: I wouldn't replace tires just based on the fact that the vehicle has been standing for 10 months. I have driven on an about 20 years old car that has stood for at least 6 months. 10 months is not that much longer than 6 months... Many people regularly store their car during the winter for 6 months, with no ill effects. Probably the only good piece of advice here is to not initially drive the Ferrari like a Ferrari should be driven. After it has been ensured the tires work fine, then you can haul ass.

Comment: 10 months is nearly double six months, 6/10 is closer to 5/10 than 10/10.... but this is a question that will attract lots of opinion...

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for the tires is:

- How much tread is left? If there is little tread and you're planning to drive in the rain, replace! In any case, replace if you're below the legal limit or near that limit.
- How old are they? If they are 10 years old or more, considering this is a Ferrari which is intended to be driven fast and not some lesser car, replace! I wouldn't risk my life on a sporty ride with 10 year old tires.
- What is the air pressure? Fill them to the correct air pressure before starting to drive this car. It is very possible that 10 month storage loses some air pressure.
- Do they look fine (after filling with air)? Drive carefully for a very short distance, then look again at the tires. As @SolarMike noticed, there may be flat spots, but I don't believe that 10 month storage is going to cause them. But you never know, so better to be safe than sorry. You should also look for dangerous cracks in the rubber in addition to flat spots. Also, check for sidewall damage; there are many questions on this site about what sidewall damage is fatal and what is not.
- Do they still hold air? Check the air pressure after driving some amount of time (carefully, of course) and few days.
- Do they have good handling properties when driving carefully?

After you have gone through the entire checklist, now is the time to enjoy and haul ass with your fine Ferrari!